# How to know the forwarding port

Tags: networking, ssh, vagrant, portforwarding, vagrantfile

I have brought a VM using vagrant.In the config vagrant file, I have given

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 830, host: 8300.
```

I'm able to ssh in to the VM by

> ssh -p 2223 vagrant@localhost

What if i want to spawn multiple VMs of same kind.How to configure the forwarding ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `auto_correct` parameter (see https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html); in case of port collision vagrant can assign another port

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 830, host: 8300, auto_correct: true
```

1. you can check `vagrant port` to displays information about guest port mappings. The command makes a warning about the value

> The forwarded ports for the machine are listed below. Please note that
>   these values may differ from values configured in the Vagrantfile if
>   the provider supports automatic port collision detection and
>   resolution.

2. just use `vagrant ssh` to ssh-in into the VM, vagrant will know which port to use.